# 3 responsive box designs using javafx

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

How do I create tree responsive box designs for javafx using scenebuilder. It should have 3 boxes that adjust to the size of the screen. Something similar to the boxes below. Any help>

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not use scenebuilder, I prefer create the FXML file by my own especially because it is not responsive.
The purpose when defining the UI of your application is to choose the good layouts. Some are more responsive than other depending on what you want to achieve.

I saw your first first post and I do not use JFoenix, then here is a **very** light/simple example with "regular" component that could help you to make your application responsive.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<fx:root xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" type="GridPane" >
    <children>
        <VBox GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" style="-fx-background-color:grey; -fx-opacity:0.7;"/>
        <VBox GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" style="-fx-background-color:grey; -fx-opacity:0.7;"/>
        <VBox GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="4" style="-fx-background-color:grey; -fx-opacity:0.7;"/>

        <HBox GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="2"  alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0">
            <Button text="ADD" style="-fx-background-color:DODGERBLUE;-fx-border-radius:10;-fx-background-radius:10"/> 
            <Button text="UPDATE" style="-fx-background-color:DODGERBLUE;-fx-border-radius:10;-fx-background-radius:10"/>
            <Button text="CLEAN" style="-fx-background-color:DODGERBLUE;-fx-border-radius:10;-fx-background-radius:10"/>
        </HBox>
    </children>
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="30.0" />
        <!-- Space -->
        <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="5.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="30.0" />
        <!-- Space -->
        <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="5.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="30.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints percentHeight="80.0" />
        <RowConstraints percentHeight="20.0" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <padding>
        <Insets top="10.0" left="10.0" bottom="10.0" right="10.0"/>
    </padding>
</fx:root>
```

This lead to something like that :
[image]

Comment: hi there, I also just finished my layout using GridPane then I saw your answer. Thank you so much for your answer. I guess gridpane really is the way to go hehe.

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't do this with Scene Builder, though. Depending on exactly how you want it to respond to resizing, a `HBox` might work here too. (Or, I guess, `BorderPane` with `HBox` with three `VBox` in the center and the three buttons in a `HBox` in the bottom.)

Comment: @James_D I don't know if the first sentence was for me, but if it was, I absolutely never said this could not work with SceneBuilder... My opinion is SceneBuilder often set a lot of hard-coded coordinates/size of components and that's why GUIs are most of time less responsive with it than by manual FXML writing.